# How do I calculate age from a given date of birth in ExtJS Framework?

Tags: extjs

Am trying to calculate age from a given date of birth in extjs, Anyone one can help?

I tried creating a function but it never worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [Ext.Date.diff](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.Date.html#method-diff) should solve this problem.

In your case the first param should be your "birthday" and the second value the current date. As unit you want the year.

Here is working code:

```
Ext.Date.diff(new Date('10-20-2000'), new Date(), 'y')
```

This should return the number 22. So your Age would be 22.

Here is a working example to show this example in an extjs form: [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3m9c)

Comment: Am using Grid where I have a date of birth field, then I have child grid where I want to show age.

Comment: You can use a calculated field in your grids store (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-calculate). That way you can use the code

Comment: Am new to ExtJs that why am stuck.

Comment: Can you give example of how to use calculated field to get age from DOB please

Comment: Here is an example with a grid: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3m9d

Comment: This helped so much

Comment: Anyone facing the same issue can reference: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic